# Merging EXRS with an alpha

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency, .exr

Can someone help me on this? I need to merge two Multichannel EXRs with an alpha mask then export to a final merged EXR.

When I link the combined channel to an alpha over node then link to output node only the rgb channel is exported

I would like something like this from nuke:

[image: screenshot from Nuke]